How to deal with mixed linear integral optimization problem with extra nonconvex but differentiable constraints?
I got a model of MILP but I want to add extra constraints.
$$
\min\{c^T x + d^T y:Ax+By=a,Cx+Dy \leq b,x,y\geq0,y \in \{0,1\}\}
$$
More specificlly, I got extra original constraints with indicator function in the following form
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\mathbb{I}(z\mu_i-1) \geq 1-\epsilon,Ex+Fy+Gz\geq0
$$
where $z$ is extra matrix variable to be optimized.
The indicator function can be approximated by logistic function $g(x)=\frac{e^{-x/{\epsilon}}}{1+e^{-x/{\epsilon}}}$, transforming the above constrints to
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}g(z\mu_i-1) \geq 1-\epsilon
$$
So how could the resulting problem be solved?

Please give your definition of $\mathbb{I}(x).$

@prubin $\mathbb{I}(x)$ is the indicator function which takes 0 when $x$ is greater than 0 and 1 otherwise.

What are $z$ and $\mu_i$? On the one hand, you say $z$ a matrix variable. On the other hand, the constraint $Ex + Fy + Gz \geq 0$ indicates it's a vectorial variable, i.e. $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

@KaimingZhang what are you modelling with the indicator constraint? Should it be interpreted as something along the lines of "$z\mu_i\leq 1$ for $1-\epsilon$ percent of the $N$ constraints?

@Sune Yes, that is the case.

I think you can achieve what you want as follows: Let $u_i$ be upper bounds on $z\mu_i$, for all $i=1,...,N$. Let furthermore $\alpha_i$ be binary variables equalling one, if $z\mu_i>1$ is allowed. Then you may formulate your requirement as
\begin{align}
&z\mu_i\leq 1+(u_i-1)\alpha_i,&&\text{for } i=1,..,N&(1)\\
&\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i\leq \lfloor N\epsilon\rfloor&&&(2)
\end{align}
This way, you allow violation of only $N\epsilon$ of the constraints ($\alpha_i=1$), stating that at least $N(1-\epsilon)$ of the constraints must be satisfied. You can round down the right hand side of (2) as the left hand side is an integer.

Thank you. I got what you mean.

@KaimingZhang, if it solves your problem, then please accept the answer for future visitors.
